# Which is correct (i miss you -or- miss you) Or both can be true In the correct English

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

Which is correct (i miss you -or- miss you)
Or both can be true In the correct English

Answer (score 1):

When people have become intimate, since they can predict so much about what each will say to the other, they naturally adopt an abbreviated "secret" language between them.  Therefore, using abbreviated speech conveys intimacy.  "Miss you" is more intimate than "I miss you".